# JaCoCo gradle plugin exclude

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I want to exclude some clasess from JaCoCo but the exclude doest seem to work.

For example i want to exclude all Java clasess that end with Dao (for example com.company.EmplyeeDao).

I have tried the following code, but it still shows up when i push this to sonar / use JacocoTestReport.

```
test {
    jacoco {
        append = true
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
        excludes = ['*Dao']
}
}
```

I'm using this in combination with Android. What is going on?

Comment: Perhaps try some variations such as `*Dao.class` or `**/*Dao.class`.

Comment: also see this gradle solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43196918/907576

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
excludes: ['**/Dao*.class']
```

But as I understand, this will exclude the class from jacoco but the Report that Jacoco creates will show you "0% of coverage":
[Gradle issue: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2955](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2955)

Comment: As I understand, yes. In the gradle issue one person excludes a yahoo and google libraries.

Comment: Won't this exclude classes that START with the word Dao? The question was for classes that END with Dao. Should the filter be '**/*Dao.class' ?

Comment: that's true what you said but there is no Dao.class file to exclude, the classes are like DaoProfile.class, DaoManager.class, etc. So that's why I'm using Dao*.class.

Answer (score 2):

For newer version of gradle (6+) use this:

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            includes = ['com/myapp/*']
            excludes = [
                    'com/myapp/folderToExclude1/*',
                    'com/myapp/folderToExclude2/*',
            ]
           limit {
                minimum = 0.85
            }
        }
    }
}
```