# How can I verify the minimum coverage with some excluded classes and with the jacoco plugin?

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I need to check the minimum coverage with the new jacoco task

**jacocoTestCoverageVerification**

This task is available with in the 3.4.1 gradle release and with the jacoco plugin >= 0.6.3

I could run another task that generates an html report with the branch coverage but now I want to use that number to make the build fail.

This is my code

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ....
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            ....
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        .....
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jar {
    baseName = "coverage-test"
}


dependencies {
    // my dependencies
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '3.4.1'
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = '0.7.9'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
    }    
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(
                dir: it,
                excludes: 
                [
                        'com/jacoco/dto/**',
                        'com/jacoco/configs/**', 
                        //and others
                ])
        })
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {

    //I tried this and it didn't work

  //   classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
  //   fileTree(
  //    dir: it,
        // excludes: 
        // [
        //      'com/jacoco/dto/**',
        //      'com/jacoco/configs/**', 
        //      //and others
        // ])
  //   })

    violationRules {
        rule {
            //Also tried this and it didn't work

           // excludes = ['com/jacoco/dto/**', ...]

            limit {
                counter = 'BRANCH'
                minimum = 0.8
            }
        }
    }
}
check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

With **classDirectories** I get the following error *Cannot get property 'files' on null object*. And with the second option (only **excludes**), the build run smoothly but It doesn't exclude any class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are measuring a different thing that you are excluding. The default JaCoCo scope is "BUNDLE" which I believe means the whole code. I've never used that. I always measure only "CLASS" scope. And it looks like you are trying to do the same.

The excludes are relative to the elements in the scope. Not sure what it means for "BUNDLE", but I am almost inclined to think it's either all or nothing. Also the excludes use different type of wildcard. Try changing your configuration to use element "CLASS" (or "PACKAGE").

```
violationRules {
    rule {
        element = 'CLASS'
        excludes = ['com.jacoco.dto.*']
        limit {
            counter = 'BRANCH'
            minimum = 0.8
        }
    }
}

check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

Comment: BTW here's a gist of what I tried in my project (and it worked): https://gist.github.com/sm4/1cacc5d8b6d99cac84336ab4df06d1bd and this is the project: https://github.com/sm4/promo-codes

Comment: Yes you were right, I was trying to measure two differents things. Also I try with your configuration to add a check rule and it works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 21):

In my case I **did** wanted to use the *BUNDLE* scope to set a threshold for the whole while excluding certain **packages** and **files**.

What worked for me in the end was adding the `classDirectories` exclude, as suggested in the original question, but inside `afterEvaluate` like this:

```
afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude:  [
                    'com/example/my/package/*',
                    'com/example/service/MyApplication.class',
                    'com/google/protobuf/*'
            ])
        })
    }
```

For reference the complete `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
apply plugin: "jacoco”

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    afterEvaluate {
        getClassDirectories().setFrom(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude:  [
                    'com/example/my/package/*',
                    'com/example/service/MyApplication.class',
                    'com/google/protobuf/*'
            ])
        })
    }

    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.79
            }
        }
    }
}


// to run coverage verification during the build (and fail when appropriate)
check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

You can find more details in my blog: http://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/04/26/gradle-verify-coverage-with-exclusions/

Comment: This is perfect. I kept trying to use excludes in the rule and failing to see any change. Thanks for figuring it out. Up voted!

Comment: In Gradle 6 at least, this fails with the following: `Cannot set the value of read-only property 'classDirectories' for task ':jacocoTestCoverageVerification' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoCoverageVerification.`

Comment: @tschumann replace 

classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect

TO

getClassDirectories().setFrom(classDirectories.files.collect

Comment: @DaniilVolkov is my hero. Thank you!

Comment: In kotlin, you can do `classDirectories.setFrom( classDirectories.files.flatMap { fileTree(it) { exclude("**/App.class") } }
    `

Comment: use: 
for kotlin: ```classDirectories.setFrom(classDirectories.files.flatMap { fileTree(it) { include("**/service/**") } })``` instead of ```afterEvaluate {...}```